# Pointer incompatible type error

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
double x = 10.08;
double *p;
p = &x;
printf("value of pointer is %d\n",p);
*p=&x;//error line
printf("value of x, *p = %lf\n",x);
return 0;
}
```

when i do it for int type(i.e. int x, int *p), its working fine. But not for double, why?

Comment: I'm a total C newb.  That said, you're having problems because in `*p=&x` you're de-referencing `p` and assigning it to a pointer to `x`.  I don't believe this has anything to do with `int` vs `double`

Comment: What do you expect that line of code to do? (Hint: you're probably wrong. Rethink pointers, and the difference between declaring a pointer and using the unary `*` operator.)

Comment: Did you mean *p =x; on the error line? Are you trying to store the value of x into the address pointed by p?

Answer (score 2):

`*p` has type `double`;  `&x` has type `double *`.  They are incompatible.

By the way, to print out pointer values, use the conversion `%p`:

```
printf("value of pointer is %p\n", p);
```

Comment: And cast to void*: `printf("value of pointer is %p\n", (void*)p);`

Answer (score 0):

`*p` is of type double. `&x` is of type pointer-to-double. Why do you expect them to be compatible?

I expect your compiler, if you turn on (and read) the warnings, to complain about that even with `int`s.

Comment: int main()
    {
    int x = 10.08;
    int *p;
    p = &x;
    printf("value of pointer is %d\n",p);
    *p=&x;
    printf("value of x, *p = %d\n",x);
    return 0;
    }
just run it, its working fine.

Comment: **Turn on warnings on your compiler**. `t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:7:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
t.c:8:4: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
`

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
 *p = &x                         with     *p = (unsigned int) &x  \\ this works
 *p = &x it means x = &x ; Not a syntax to follow
```

Though this is not to be followed in c because *p ,it inturns means x value and you wanna store the address in the x value but you did not declare it as the pointer but just a normal variable.

however with the int you dont get any error but a warning indicating that

```
 non portable assigment
```

I dont know the deep roots but as for my investigation,i guess the pointers save the address in some other format but show us the integer format

```
int x;
int *p;
p = &x ;
*p = &x ; warning non portable assignment replace with *p = (unsigned int) &x

using typecasting (unsigned int ) coverts the address format to integer format
I guess So . May be the address format and integer format are different
Thats why you cant assign address to a variable unless it is typecasted
but pointers dont need them because as they are invented to store the address
This is what i think from my investigation
```

But i highly recommend not to follow The above syntax.

people dont use double pointer always Instead go for void pointer